# Render jQuery template on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, jquery-templates

Is it possible to render jQuery template on server? I wanna define jQuery template, render GSP using it than make AJAX request and update view on client.

I can render simple GSP template and return it as AJAX anser but it has limitations - I need return not only HTML content but also JS vars

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it if you put the js in the

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

tag in the template to do some js call but be aware of the same origin policy. You might not be able do cross domain ajax call.

Comment: this will be rendered on the client side, not server side

Comment: the above is rendered on the server with the gsp template but the js execution is happening on the client side - which js alway executes on the client side. Can you give some more detail of what you want to do?

Comment: evanwong, I think this solution is correct but not the best one: you should correctly pass params to js; js should be placed somewhere (.gsp or.js in this case?); returned from server html is not fully constructed (it should be completed by client js script). In my opinion the best solution (if it's possible) is to have GSP custom tag to render jquery template (or any other) on server using some data and then (if it's required) use it on client